# Typescript Error Type 'ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'Item[]'

Tags: typescript, ionic3

In my ionic project, I want to get the rows from a table of a postgreSql data base, then assign the rows to a item[]: currentItems.

I check the return rows from postgreSql, it is in format as:

```
[
 anonymous 
 {
   name: jack,
   email: jack@gmail.com
 }
 anonymous 
 {
   name: mark,
   email: mark@gmail.com
 }
]
```

however, when I assign it to item[]: currentItems, I get the error as:
**Typescript Error Type 'ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'Item[]'.**

Below are part of my inoic code:

item.ts:

```
export class Item {

  constructor(fields: any) {
    // Quick and dirty extend/assign fields to this model
    for (const f in fields) {
      // @ts-ignore
      this[f] = fields[f];
    }
  }

}
```

list-master.ts:

```
export class ListMasterPage {
  currentItems: Item[];

  params: { uid: string } = {
    uid: "test"
  };

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
    public items: Items,
    public modalCtrl: ModalController,
    public globalvar: GlobalvarProvider,
    public toastCtrl: ToastController) {

    this.params.uid = this.globalvar.userIdentifier
    this.items.query(this.params).subscribe((resp) => {
    /* here assign the received rows from database to the currentItems */
      this.currentItems = resp;
    }, (err) => {
    });;
  }
```

items.ts

```
export class Items {

  constructor(public api: Api) { }

  query(params?: any) {
    /* here get the rows from the postgresql database, I have confirmed the data received is in the format mentioned in above question description */
    return this.api.get('getfriends', params);
  }

  add(item: Item) {
  }

  delete(item: Item) {
  }

}
```

Thanks

Comment: To confirm, if you `console.log(resp)`, what exactly do you see?  The response probably needs some kind of manual conversion to an `Item[]`.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen, thanks Matt. it show:    resp is: [object Object],[object Object]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you probably have valid plain objects from parsing JSON.  To troubleshoot why TypeScript thinks the type is `ArrayBuffer`, I'd need to see the declaration of the `get` method that is called in the `Items.prototype.query` method.  If you want `Item` objects instead of plain objects, you'll have to instantiate them yourself, e.g.:

```
this.currentItems = (<any[]>resp).map((i) => new Item(i));
```

or use a serialization library.